# How to set unique_together for a user field

Tags: django-models

I am learning Django. I am creating app where I have a model Employer.
In a database, I want to keep only one record for fields user and website.

I tried to use unique_together in my model but during migration I got the following error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: employer_employer.user_id, employer_employer.website

Can you please advice me what is a problem? Maybe this is not a good way how to do it?
Thanks!

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    USER = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

    user = models.ForeignKey(USER, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_size = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'website')
```

Comment: That means there are already records that violate the constraint. You will first have to fix those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use unique_together in my model but during migration I got the following error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: employer_employer.user_id, employer_employer.website`

This means the migration is perfectly fine. It means there is already data in the database that violates the constraint, so you will first need to go through the fact that there are `Employer` objects in the database with the same user and the same `website`.

You can find such `User`s effectively with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Employee.objects.values('user', 'website').annotate(count=Count('pk')).filter(
    count__gt=1
)
```

then you will have to fix these `Employer` records.

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).